# item tracking for a self-service storage user

Tags: android, ios

I need a mobile app to track physical belongings that I either move from home to a [self-service storage facility](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_storage), or move back home from there. Like books, off-season clothes and sports gear, rarely-used gadgets and DIY tools.

Apparently its tracked items should be photo-centric, but sometimes should have a text caption (ideally searchable) and ideally some hierarchy (eg to group books into physical boxes where they are kept).

Unlike typical photo storage services, it should be very easy with a mobile app to move an item between "at the storage" and "at home" states / "albums".

Platform-wise: iOS is critical at least for read-only access; Android would be a major plus.

Answer (score 3):

### [Trello](http://www.trello.com)

Trello is a list application.  It is in particular marketted for task lists -which it excells at. But I have put it to other uses.

You create a nunber of lists. In your case 2: home and storage.
Fir each item you are tracking you create a card. Which can have a picture. You then drag and drop it between the home and storage lists.
Trello will track whi moved it and when.

I've used the web and android intrfaces. Quiet good. Supports directly taking picture from phone. My friend s say the iphone version is good too.
On the Web-browser interface to attach a photo you need to use the "Attachment" option inside the card details (it is actualyl easier on phone).

[image: example of using trello to track storage]

Comment: When on pc I'll make a screenshot fo this.

Comment: Not sure it fit the purpose well: it's not photo-centric enough. You can't make a photo - give it an optional comment - make next photo - proceed to next. Instead, you need to give every item some name, then go deep through UI to attach a photo... Looks like it will take way too long to process several dozen books, for example.

Comment: It is a bit more photo-centric on android (than on Web/PC). I haven't tested IOS, so can't comment.
(I agree there should be a better option than this, but I am not aware of it).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but just in case of interest:
There are a few android apps, that can help you with this e.g.

- [Magic Home Inventory](https://apkpure.com/magic-home-inventory/net.twisterrob.inventory)
- [Sortly](https://apkpure.com/sortly-inventory-simplified/com.sortly.mythings).

You can make "home" and "self storage" as rooms or categories. You can take photos and move between categories etc.

You will find a few others on apkpure.com, but you will have to try out to see if they meet all your requirements.